# python threading.Timer behaves differntly on linux computers

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have written some code for periodically running some function using python library `threading.Timer`. It uses some external class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session  # session is an external class instance

    def doPeriodically(self):

        self.session.open_spectrum(spectrum_file)  # open spectrum file using session

        t = threading.Timer(5, self.doPeriodically, [], {})  # set up a timer

    def startPeriodicJob(self):

        self.doPeriodically()

mc = MyClass(session)
mc.startPeriodicJob()
```

I run my extension on my laptop with Ubuntu 13.10 and python 2.7.5+ and Tkinter Revision: 81008, everything runs very well. But when I copy the same code to my desktop with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and python 2.7.3 and Tkinter Revision: 81008, the code always breaks with Error (see below).

But NOTE: My code is meant to be an extension to [sparky](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/home/sparky/manual/extensions.html#WriteExtension) which ships python 2.4.2 within it. Therefore the code ought be to interpreted by that python 2.4.2. It can be also seen in the following error message.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/src/sparky/platforms/linux-2.6.9/python-2.4.2/lib/python2.4/threading.py", line 442, in __bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/src/sparky/platforms/linux-2.6.9/python-2.4.2/lib/python2.4/threading.py", line 605, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/own/code/MyClass.py", line 64, in doPeriodically
    self.session.do_jobs() 
Error: session 0 not found
```

The paths to python 2.4.2 do not exist on my computer. It is from the pre-compiled binary program which I write extension for.

The puzzle is, the code works very well on one computer but not on the other. And it seems it is the python 2.4.2 shipped within the program that interprets my extension (MyClass.py), therefore the python version on the two computers should not play a role here.

What could be the problem? Can different threads use the same Session instance to execute its member functions?

It does not help if I pass the Session instance to the function:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session  # session is an external class instance

    def doPeriodically(self, sess):

        sess.open_spectrum(spectrum_file)  # open spectrum file using session

        t = threading.Timer(5, self.doPeriodically, [sess,])  # set up a timer

    def startPeriodicJob(self):

        self.doPeriodically(self.session)

mc = MyClass(session)
mc.startPeriodicJob()
```

ps. the Session class can be found in the sparky package:
https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/home/sparky/

Comment: Many GUI libraries (like TKinter) can only do their work from the main thread of a process.  Or from the thread in which their main loop was started.  Or they need to be configured to accept other threads (by calling a `start_threaded()` or similar).  So the best way would be to try to let only the main thread handle everything which is connected to the GUI and use other threads to do everything else.  Second best solution is to find a way to tweak the GUI library in accepting other threads, if possible.

Comment: I had the same worry when the code did not work on the desktop. But then the code started to work on the other computer. Seemingly the Tkinter GUI could cope with the newly spawned thread, well, sometimes.

Comment: TKinter comes in different flavors.  I've still got a bunch of old programs which are using sth threaded (or not threaded) and which today won't work with the current tkinter versions because of this :-/

Comment: OK, but you see the Tkinter on the two computers are the same, no to speak the program also ships its own tkinter library...

Comment: Oh, I understand.  Then this cannot be the reason.  Maybe if you tell us more about that `session` there?  Where does it come from?  What code creates it?  We cannot reproduce your situation; your source does not show this vital part.

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly. It is from the sparky package, which is written ca. 10 years ago and not actively developed anymore....

Comment: Maybe if you add the _code_ which read sth like `session = …`.  It's just searching in the dark, but that part is definitely missing currently.

Comment: the function session.open_spectrum() is invoked in the function which is periodically executed using threading.Timer. I am also reading the code in Sparky in order to find some clue ..